# What is wrong with my SQLiteParameters?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have made this function for inserting values into my database. It has worked before. The only thing I have changed is adding Parameters to handle the input. Now when I try to use it, I get this error: `SQLite error (1): near "@valuesParam": syntax error`

Please see my code below. What am I doing wrong?

```
    // Inserts value(s) into colum(s) of a certain table in the database.
    public void InsertToDatabase(string table, string columns, string values)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(conString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            using(SQLiteCommand insertionCommand = new SQLiteCommand(dbConnection))
            {
                insertionCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + columns + ") VALUES @valuesParam";
                insertionCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valuesParam", values);
                insertionCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't use parameters for your tablename. Just type it. Parameters are only for the values, not for table or columns names.

Comment: Ahh I didn't know, I'm such a newbie. Thanks! Makes sense as well.

Comment: @Pikoh I removed the parameters for the table and column names, but it still fails.

Comment: edit your question, put the how is now the code and what exception throws

Comment: @Pikoh there you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@valuesParam is not in brackets in your command ...
I would however much rather pass the values for the insert as a list that you should enumerate

As an Example:

```
    public void InsertToDatabase(string table, string columns, List<string> values)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(conString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            using (SQLiteCommand insertionCommand = new SQLiteCommand(dbConnection))
            {
                insertionCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + columns + ") VALUES (";
                for (int i=0;i<values.Count;i++)
                {
                    //add in the parameter to the insert command
                    insertionCommand.CommandText += "@val" + i.ToString() + ",";
                //add the parameter
                    insertionCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val"+i.ToString(), values[i]);
                }
                //remove the last comma from the insert command and add a bracket
                insertionCommand.CommandText = insertionCommand.CommandText.Substring(0, insertionCommand.CommandText.Length - 1);
                insertionCommand.CommandText+=")";

                insertionCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    //this is the dummy function to show how to populate the list to pass as the values
    public void UseInsert()
    {
        List<string> insertValues = new List<string> { };
        insertValues.Add("Bruce");
        insertValues.Add("Wayne");

        InsertToDatabase("people", "Name,Surname", insertValues);
    }
```

Comment: Does that mean I have to add a parameter for each of the values I want to insert into the database? Because otherwise it just gives me an error that I only provide one value for six columns.

Comment: No, you just pass a list of values. I will edit my post with an example

Comment: Not to confuse you, but I also highly recommend using try catch around the dbConnection.Open(); and insertionCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: I would also use a stringbuilder to create the insert statement, it is faster and also easier to remove the last trainling comma

Comment: sorry, trailing comma

Comment: I use the try catch block around the call to this method.

Comment: While that does work, I found it much better to do each error causing statement individually, you can then handle each part separately for example, retry the open a few times with a delay between each try.